# How to make fields editable only that are selected in configuration(Odoo16)?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-16

I have a many2many field defined on model "ir.model.fields" set in configuration screen. Where manager can select fields that should be editable by user.
Now , my complete form is readonly but I want to make only that fields editable which are selected in configuration. In short, a user can edit only that fields that are allowed to edit.

How to use this condition in Odoo16 ?

I tried below:
I created manay2many computed field that have all fields that are allowed to edit in employee form and add set attrs in field in xml like this:

editable_fields --> computed many2many field

But still not working!!

Comment: Please add [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.